# Should common patterns be organized as L3 constructs or stacks in AWS CDK apps?

Tags: aws-cdk

I started learning AWS CDK, and I found a L3 [construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/constructs.html) is a means to organize common patterns of building blocks;

- see the constructs composition to form higher level construct illustrated here [image]

At the same time, CDK stacks are equivalent to Cloudformation stacks, and stack is also a unit to form composition (through nested stacks), which is typically a resuable unit of AWS components;

- see the nested stack composition illustrated here in the [cloudformation doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html);

Now I have the question when we should build L3 construct as reusable patterns solutions and when we should build stack as reusable patterns solutions.